# Connecting two containers with Kubernetes using environment variables

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I'm new to k8s and need some direction on how to troubleshoot.

I have a postgres container and a graphql container. The graphql container is tries to connect to postgres on startup.

### Problem

The graphql container can't connect to postgres. This is the error on startup:

{"internal":"could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "my-app" (xxx.xx.xx.xxx) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n",
"path":"$","error":"connection error","code":"postgres-error"}

My understanding is that the graphql-container doesn't recognize the IP `my-app (xxx.xx.xx.xxx)`. This is the actual Pod Host IP, so I'm confused as to why it doesn't recognize it. How do I troubleshoot errors like these?

### What I tried

- Hardcoding the host in the connection uri in deployment.yaml to the actual pod host IP. Same error.
- Bashed into the graphql container and verified that it had the correct env values with the `env` command.

### deployment.yaml

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: my-app
...
  - name: my-graphql-container
    image: image-name:latest
    env:
    - name: MY_POSTGRES_HOST
      value: my-app
    - name: MY_DATABASE
      value: db
    - name: MY_POSTGRES_DB_URL # the postgres connection url that the graphql container uses
      value: postgres://$(user):$(pw)@$(MY_POSTGRES_HOST):5432/$(MY_DATABASE)
...
  - name: my-postgres-db
    image: image-name:latest
```

Comment: The `MY_POSTGRES_HOST` hostname should match the name of the Service in front of the database.  Does it?

Comment: Yes it does, both containers are in the `my-app` service.

Comment: That's not generally a good pattern; it's better to run one deployment for the (stateless) `my-app` and a separate stateful set for `my-app-db`, with corresponding services for each.  If you have readiness probes on your pod, there's also a chicken-and-egg problem where the service won't attach to the pod until the pod shows ready, but the pod can't show ready until it can connect to the service.

Comment: I see...So if I create a separate service called `my-app-db`, would I just set the `host` as `my-app-db` in the graphql container's connection uri? Also, do databases need a liveness/readiness probe? I currently dont have them set for the database.

Comment: That setup sounds right.  A readiness probe is a good idea.

Comment: @DavidMaze I got it working :) Thanks for the tip David. I broke out app and db into separate services and now they are able to talk to each other!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [k8s docs about pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#using-pods) you can read:

> Pods in a Kubernetes cluster are used in two main ways:
>
> - **Pods that run a single container.** [...]
> - **Pods that run multiple containers that need to work together**. [...]
>
> > ***Note***: Grouping multiple co-located and co-managed containers in a
> > single Pod is a relatively advanced use case. You should use this
> > pattern only in specific instances in which your containers are
> > tightly coupled.
>
> ***Each Pod is meant to run a single instance of a given
> application***. [...]

---

Notice that your deployment doesn't fit this descriprion because you are trying to run two applications in one pod.

Remember to always use one pod per container and only use multiple containers per pod if it's impossible to separate them (and for some reason they have to run together).

And the rest was already mentioned by David.